# Highstock xAxis Label rotation

Tags: highcharts

The rotation of labels for highstock charts does not seem to work

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/py9cjw1z/

```
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    autoRotation: [-45,-45,-45,-45,-45,-45,-45,-45,-45,-45]
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rotation` instead of `autoRotation` property:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        rotation: -45
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/27jhc9u3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.rotation